Which prepositions will be correct?
I want to say that something will be finished before some point in the future.

A1) I will have finished it next year
A2)  I will have finished it by next year


B1) I will have finished at 7 pm
B2) I will have finished by 7 pm

Do I need "by" in both examples or are all the different versions fine, but mean something different?

Which prepositions are correct. The choice of one preposition over another is unrelated to the future; the prepositions would be the same if you were writing about the past.

A1 and A2 are both fine and understood to be the same.
The phrase "have finished it next year" has hits as shown.
Though "have finished it by next year" has no exact hits, we can find examples for "have finished it by next" in similar usages.
In B1 and B2, the omitted it after finished is understood, but I would prefer to have it.
B2 with by is fine, but B1 with at is not.
We don't use the perfect with time reference, like at 7pm.  To use at, we remove the perfect, but the sentence would mean something else: I will finish it at 7 pm.  It no longer means finishing before the stated time.

What about these ones? 1"I will have done it  in January and on Monday". Are these time expressions correct here?

@Gregor, I saw your new question.  We will hence look at that instead of this.

so please comment on my new question
